# Block or Remove all incoming notification of other apps programatically in android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, push-notification, notifications

**Hello everyone , hope you all are doing good. I want to ask how to remove or block any incoming notification (coming from other apps like whats app, instagram etc) in android programatically.**

Below is the code snippet i am using to block the notification but it's not working.

```
class BlockNotification : NotificationListenerService() {
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return super.onBind(intent)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
      
        Log.d("Msg", "Notification arrived ${sbn.packageName},${sbn.id},${sbn.key},${sbn.uid}")
      
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            cancelNotification(sbn.packageName, sbn.tag, sbn.id)
        } else {
            cancelNotification(sbn.key)
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    override fun onNotificationRemoved(sbn: StatusBarNotification) {
        // Implement what you want here
        Log.d("Msg", "Notification Removed")
        clearNotofication(sbn.uid)
        cancelNotification(sbn.key)
    }

    private fun clearNotofication(notificationId: Int) {
        val ns = NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
        val nMgr = this.getSystemService(ns) as NotificationManager
        nMgr.cancel(notificationId)
    }
}
```

Also declared the service in manifest file.

```
 <service
            android:name=".utils.BlockNotification"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.notification.default_filter_types"
                android:value="conversations|alerting" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.notification.disabled_filter_types"
                android:value="ongoing|silent" />
        </service>
```

If anyone have any idea , please let me know !!

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

you can get the context by signing context in your class's parameter

then you can clear all of the notifications in your notification  Bar

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

or in your case remove only one notification by using it's id like you did in your last function

```
notificationManager.cancle(notification_id);
```

or using with a tag I don't think you want this but to let you know it is exist

```
notificationManager.cancle(your_tag, notification_id);
```

you check the [Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#cancel(java.lang.String,%20int))  for explanation